# How to use apt-get in laravel homestead on a Linux Mint Box?

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

I have a laravel homestead box installed on my Linux Mint computer. For my project I would need to install inkscape in the box for EPS to SVG conversion.

When I run vagrant ssh and in the box then sudo apt-get update I get a 404 error for all sources. But when I ping the IP address, it finds the address.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

vagrant@homestead:~$ ping 91.189.91.15
PING 91.189.91.15 (91.189.91.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.91.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=566 ms
```

Is there something I need to do to in my homestead environment to get apt-get to work?

Comment: Try to apt-get update first.

Comment: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Of course this needs sudo too

Comment: It's the sudo apt-get update that fails to fetchs.

Comment: I think it's not a problem with homestead, it's something with the repo itself

Comment: Yeah, I get a 404 on that URL from here, too.

Comment: Just a note regarding networking: if your HTTP request received a '404 Not Found' response, then that means that the name resolved to an IP address, a TCP connection was accepted by whatever program (probably a web server) was listening for connections, and sent a valid HTTP response. The 'Not Found' refers to the specific file requested, not to the entire server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be linked to using a non LTS version of ubuntu called an End of life version. I have seen similar errors come as a result of using a EOF version. As those have discontinued support. Since Mint uses ubuntu and debain as a base. You can check if your mint box's ubuntu release/kernel lies in the end of life version on the following :

To see what your mint box is using-> http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php corelate that 
with the ubuntu official site if need be -> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Anyways, the simplest solution to fix this is to do the following two steps:

1- Backup your sources list -> sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup

2- Open the sources file "/etc/apt/sources.list" Rename all the instances of us.archive or archive in http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ to

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Also do the same for the http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/..

3- Run sudo apt-get update after doing the above.

That should fix the issue. you can also look into upgrading to a release of mint that has ubuntu's LTS supported version as a base. http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php